# Setting alarm android

Tags: android

I have a string that may contain value 07:00 or 11:00 0r 15:00

I want to set alarm for that time for today. it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a calendar object set to midnight, and then offset it by the hours and minutes you have:

```
String alarm = "13:00";
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

long millis = c.getTime().getTime();
millis += 1000*60*60*Integer.parseInt(alarm.substring(0, 2));
millis += 1000*60*Integer.parseInt(alarm.substring(3, 5));
```

### Demo

An alternative to this would be to use two `SimpleDateFormat` masks to parse out the timestamp you want.